# Loop ASCII to Raster

Tags: arcpy, esri-ascii-raster, for-loop

I need to transform multiple ASCII files into a .tiff.
I started by created the following python script but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Maybe It's something with the loop? Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
 import arcpy 
 import glob

 asciiFolder = glob.glob('D:\Maxent\outputs\*.asc') print asciiFolder

 outRaster= "D:\Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland\MR_ascii_naar_TIFF"

 for x in asciiFolder:
     arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(x, outRaster)
```

The error is telling me that the parameters are incorrect. But I almost exactly used the example code (tool page from Esri), so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The error:

```
= RESTART: D:/Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland/ascii_naar_tiff_script.py =
['D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Aeshna_juncea.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Andrena_chrysosceles.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Argynnis_niobe.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Autographa_gamma.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Bombus_pascuorum.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Bombus_terrestris.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Ceriagrion_tenellum.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Cicindela_campestris.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Coccinella_septempunctata.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Erythromma_najas.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Formica_rufa.asc', 'D:\\Maxent\\outputs\\Graphoderus_bilineatus.asc']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland/ascii_naar_tiff_script.py", line 12, in <module>
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(x, outRaster)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.7\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 2467, in ASCIIToRaster
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000878: Output raster: The length of the grid base name in D:\Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland\MR_ascii_naar_TIFF is longer than 13.
Failed to execute (ASCIIToRaster).

>>>
```

Comment: Please read the description of the error `The length of the grid base name in D:\Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland\MR_ascii_naar_TIFF is longer than 13.
Failed to execute (ASCIIToRaster).`, I think it's more than explicit.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem here is that the name "MR_ascii_naar_TIFF" is not a TIFF file reference, so ArcGIS is attempting to create an ancient Grid format dataset instead (for which this name is too long). "MR_ascii_naar.tif" would be a legal name for a GeoTIFF output.

However, you have another fundamental issue with your script -- by iterating the list you will get an "output exists" error on the second ASCII file (either that, or you'll clobber the existing raster). What you really need, if you want to mosaic these images together, is to mosaic them:

```
import arcpy 
import glob

asciiFolder = glob.glob('D:\Maxent\outputs\*.asc') print asciiFolder

outRaster= "D:\Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland\MR_ascii_naar.tif"

tmpNames = []
i = 0
for x in asciiFolder:
    i += 1
    tmpRaster = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(outRaster),"tmp{:d}.tif".format(i))
    arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion(x, tmpRaster)
    tmpNames.append(tmpRaster)

arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(
        ",".join(tmpNames),
        os.path.dirname(outRaster),
        os.path.basename(outRaster),
        "prjname_needed_here.prj",
        "8_BIT_UNSIGNED", 
        "cellsize", "1", "LAST","FIRST")

for tmpRaster in tmpNames:
    ArcPy.Delete_management(tmpRaster)
```

*Note: Script not tested; You will need the correct parameters for your data in the mosaic request -- see the* [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Erik answer, if you want to use back slashes for the image path you need to escape the string like this:

```
outRaster= r"D:\Insectennetwerk Provincie Friesland\MR_ascii_naar_TIFF"
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you had made the effort of googling your error message, you'd have gotten [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00876-00900-000878.htm).

The (kind of obvious) solution as provided by ESRI is: shorten your grid name to 13 characters. Also avoid spaces, use only A-Z and underscore and don't let it start with a number.